# Why move constructor is not called in my code ? Also why dtor is not called just to destroy temp obj?

Tags: c++, move-constructor

Lines in my code

```
student g1(student("Larry"));//why move ctor is not called after overloaded ctor???
student g2 = "Delta";//Also here,why move ctor is not called after overloaded ctor???
```

Also why dtor is not called for unnamed temporary objects created just after????

Actually i am confused totally ,when move ctor is called .
On the other hand i have also observed that if i try to push back a temp obj in to a vector expecting obj type elements ,there move ctor is called ,

```
vector<student> list{};
list.push_back(student("vickey"));
```

Here, first vickey temp object created then move to the vector by calling move constructor, because `student("vickey")` is an rvalue. Isn't it?

If above is valid then why here its not valid?

```
student g1(student("Larry"));
student g2 = "Delta";
```

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
//===================class declaration============================
class student{
private:
    char *name;
public:
    student();
    student(const char *str);
    ~student();
    student(student &&rhs) noexcept;
    
};
//======================impelmentation=========================
student::student(){
    cout<<"default"<<endl;
    name = new char[5];
    strcpy(name,  "None");
}
student::student(const char *str)
    :name{nullptr}{
        cout << "overloaded" << endl;
        if(str == nullptr){
            name = new char[5];
            strcpy(name, "None");
        }else{
        name = new char[strlen(str) + 1];
        strcpy(name, str);
        }
}

student::student(student &&rhs) noexcept
    :name{rhs.name}{
        cout << "Move ctor" << endl;
        rhs.name = nullptr;
        
}

student::~student(){
    if(name == nullptr)
        cout<<"dtor : nullptr"<< endl;
    else{
        cout<<"dtor : "<<name<< endl;
        delete [] name;
    }
}

//===================================main=====================================
int main() {
    student g1(student("Larry"));
    student g2 = "Delta";
    cout<<"\n=========================================================\n"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
overloaded
overloaded

=========================================================

dtor : Delta
dtor : Larry
```

Comment: Those are constructors; they don't need to move.  `student g0 = "Alpha"; student g3 = std::move(g0);` would do a move.

Comment: The compiler may optimize a lot of things for you. Like to construct an object directly instead of invoking a copy/move constructor. Yet, even if the compiler omits the call to either of these, they should still be accessible when used.

Comment: @Eljay can u please explain me in detail when move ctor will be called , and why here not??

Comment: A move ctor will be called when an existing object is being move constructed into a newly constructed object.  It may also be moved when a temporary object is used to move construct into a newly constructed object (but that likely may be optimized by the compiler).  Because of the rules of the language, side-effects (like printing something in the constructor) cannot be relied upon since constructors can be elided.  Lesson is:  constructors should construct objects into a coherent state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
 student g1(student("Larry"));
```

The `g1` is constructed using a constructor due to [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). In order to move construct `g1`, you would need to do it explicitly in this case:

```
student g1(std::move(student("Larry")));
```

In the case of `vec.push_back(student("vickey"));` the move constructor is called since `std::vector` has `push_back(T&&)` overload and the `student("vickey")` is an rvalue. This overload resolution leads to invocation of the type's move constructor *(implicitly)*. There's no way to elide copying/moving the object into `vector`. So, the best we can hope for is the move constructor.

As we already have seen, you can do similarly in your user code, by using `std::move`.

Note, user code (generally) should not use `std::move`. It mostly intended for class implementations.

Comment: Moving a temporary is pointless. Even a code smell, indicative of cargo cult programming. The library sees nothing a user defined type doesn't in this case. Move-semantics are ingrained in the core language.

Comment: And your edit contradicts your own answer. You say a `std::move` is needed here, and then say it's ill-advised!?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I did not said `std::move` is **needed**. I said that the OP **would need** it, for whatever reason the OP needs to do it.

Comment: @rawrex as u have said that The g1 is copy constructed from a temporary object. How it is copy constructed? even we know that student("Larry") is an r-value,then the expression should be equivalent to student g1(r-value); that should invoke move ctor,I think.

Comment: @SaurabhRaj corrected the answer. Check the edit.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica hey, friend! I want to thank you for your input! I got to admit, I did messed that one up.